# How to resize Excel VBA text when inputting into Powerpoint?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Currently taking data from an Excel table and inputting it into Powerpoint slides. How could I resize the text below from the table? Powerpoint currently autosizes it to font size 18.

```
Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 150).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters = "TEST " & Cells(Row, col + 1)
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Did you type that code or pasted it from somewhere? All these chained dots are asking for trouble - declare a `Shape` variable and `Set` it to the result of `Shapes.AddTextbox`, then you should get intellisense on `.TextFrame`, and your question should answer itself.

Comment: BTW Excel is pretty much irrelevant here, but that unqualified `Cells` call is implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is - which is frail/bug-prone. Consider working off a `Worksheet` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '~TextRange.Charaters.' But it is usually used to change some part of a text.

```
~ TextRange.Characters(1, 2).Font.Bold = True ' sets the font of first 2 letters to bold style
```

Instead, '~.TextRange' or '~.TextRange.Text' would be just good enough.
And the size of a text can be set with '~ TextRange.Font.Size = xx'

After applying  Mathieu Guindon's advice, your code would look like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set ppPres = ActivePresentation
Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
Set ppShape = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 150)
With ppShape
    .Name = "MyShape 1"
    With .TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Test" & Sht.Cells(xRow, xColumn + 1) ' "Excel Cell Value"
        .Font.Size = 15
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 125, 255)
        'change first 2 letters to red color
        .Characters(1, 2).Font.Color.RGB = rgbRed
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Please give a name to Powerpoint shape object, so that you can control the object later by using its name like '~.Shapes("Given name").Textframe.TextRange.~ = ~ '